# How to keep a button disabled when reload the page, using localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Im doing a webstore with products. The button disables after 10 click, its when the stock is out, the stock is 10. Im saving data in localStorage about the product and how many.

My problem is that when I reload the page I can click on the button again even if its more than 10 items. How can I keep the button disabled even after reload the page. Ive tried save the button in localStorage and with an if statement check if its in localStorage and then keep the button disabled.

the code of the button:

```js
if (products[i].inCart === 10) {
  const disabled = (euro[i].disabled = true);
  localStorage.setItem("disabled", disabled);
  let newDisabled = localStorage.getItem("disabled");
  newDisabled = JSON.parse(newDisabled);
  if (newDisabled === true) {
    euro[i].disabled = true;
  }
}
```

the hole script:

```js
let cartNr = document.getElementById("cartNr");
const lang1 = document.querySelector(".lang1");
cartNr = 1;

let products = [
  {
    id: 0,
    namn: "Sneaker1",
    img: "//shelta.se/pub_images/original/DV1129-300_1.jpg?timestamp=1677759773",
    pris: 1500,
    lager: 10,
    inCart: 0,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    namn: "Sneaker2",
    img: "https://shelta.se/pub_images/original/AH6789-006_1.jpg",
    pris: 1500,
    lager: 10,
    inCart: 0,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    namn: "Sneaker3",
    img: "https://shelta.se/pub_images/original/DV1129-001_1.jpg?timestamp=1673044814",
    pris: 1500,
    lager: 10,
    inCart: 0,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    namn: "Sneaker4",
    img: "https://shelta.se/pub_images/original/AH6789-001_1.jpg?timestamp=1609192138",
    pris: 1500,
    lager: 10,
    inCart: 0,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    namn: "Sneaker5",
    img: "https://shelta.se/pub_images/original/DM2361-100_0.jpg?timestamp=1628091117",
    pris: 1500,
    lager: 10,
    inCart: 0,
  },
];

const euro = document.querySelectorAll(".euro");

for (let i = 0; i < euro.length; i++) {
  euro[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    cartNumbers(products[i]);
    totalCost(products[i]);

    if (products[i].inCart === 10) {
      const disabled = (euro[i].disabled = true);
      localStorage.setItem("disabled", disabled);
      let newDisabled = localStorage.getItem("disabled");
      newDisabled = JSON.parse(newDisabled);
      if (newDisabled === true) {
        euro[i].disabled = true;
      }
    }
  });
}

function onLoadCartNumbers() {
  let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem("cartNumbers");
  if (productNumbers) {
    lang1.innerHTML = `<div id="cartNr">${(cartNr = productNumbers)}</div>`;
  }
}

function cartNumbers(product) {
  console.log("the product clicked is", product);
  let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem("cartNumbers");
  productNumbers = parseInt(productNumbers);
  if (productNumbers) {
    localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", productNumbers + 1);
    lang1.innerHTML = `<div id="cartNr">${(cartNr = productNumbers + 1)}</div>`;
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("cartNumbers", 1);
    lang1.innerHTML = `<div id="cartNr">${(cartNr = 1)}</div>`;
  }

  setItems(product);
}

function setItems(product) {
  let cartItems = localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
  cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
  console.log(cartItems); //funkar
  if (cartItems != null) {
    if (cartItems[product.id] == undefined) {
      cartItems = {
        ...cartItems,
        [product.id]: product,
      };
      console.log(cartItems);
    } else {
      cartItems[product.id].inCart += 1;

      product.inCart++;

      console.log(cartItems); //funkar
    }
  } else {
    product.inCart = 1;
    cartItems = {
      [product.id]: product,
    };
    console.log(cartItems); //funkar
  }

  localStorage.setItem("productsInCart", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("productsInCart"));
}

function totalCost(product) {
  let cartCost = localStorage.getItem("totalCost");
  if (cartCost != null) {
    cartCost = parseInt(cartCost);
    localStorage.setItem("totalCost", cartCost + product.pris);
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("totalCost", product.pris);
  }
}

async function patchPost(obj) {
  const baseURL = `https://webstore-22fa4-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/`;
  const url = baseURL + `Products.json`;
  const init = {
    method: "PUT",
    body: JSON.stringify(obj),
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    },
  };

  const response = await fetch(url, init);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
}
let obj = Object.values(products);
patchPost(obj);
console.log(obj);

onLoadCartNumbers();
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting `addEventListener` would not be a good idea in a `for loop`. Instead you can add the `eventListener` on `parent` which contains these buttons and `useCapture` to trickle down the event and identify the `target button`. Another thing, you will need a `reference` against which you'll save which button should be disabled. What I get from your code, you have multiple items in your cart and you want to disable it if it exceeds the max quantity, and this state should be maintained on page refresh.

I have created a simple utility which you can refer to and modify your code accordingly.

```js
const prArr = [
  { id: 1, lager: 10, inCart: 0 },
  { id: 2, lager: 10, inCart: 0 },
  { id: 3, lager: 10, inCart: 0 },
  { id: 4, lager: 10, inCart: 0 },
  { id: 5, lager: 10, inCart: 0 },
  { id: 6, lager: 10, inCart: 0 },
  { id: 7, lager: 10, inCart: 0 }
]

const disabledItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('disabledItems'))
if (!disabledItems) {
  localStorage.setItem('disabledItems', JSON.stringify([]))
}
document.querySelector('span').textContent = localStorage.getItem('disabledItems')

prArr.forEach(pr => {
  const btn = document.createElement('button')
  btn.setAttribute('id', pr.id)
  btn.textContent = `btn ${pr.id}`
  const container = document.querySelector('div')
  container.appendChild(btn)
})

const disableButtons = () => {
  disabledItems?.forEach(item => {
    document.getElementById(item.id).setAttribute('disabled', true)
  })
}

document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const tg = event.target
  if (tg.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    const clickedPr = prArr.find((pr) => {
      return pr.id === +tg.id
    })
    if (clickedPr.inCart < clickedPr.lager - 1) clickedPr.inCart++
    else {
      tg.setAttribute('disabled', true)
      disabledItems.push({ id: tg.id })
      localStorage.setItem('disabledItems', JSON.stringify(disabledItems))
      document.querySelector('span').textContent = localStorage.getItem('disabledItems')
    }
  }
}, true)

disableButtons()
```

```html
<div></div>
disabled butttons: <span></span>
```

You can run the above code locally, `localStorage` will not work in the snippet.